# Laravel APi resource whenLoaded

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to load a model relation using whenLoaded like so:

Yard Resource

```
'latest_inspection' => new Inspection($this->whenLoaded('latestInspection'))
```

Which is working fine, but on the Inspection resource there are some other relations that aren't being included:

Inspection Resource

```
'completed_tasks' => TaskResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('tasks')),
'feedings' => FeedResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('feeds')),
```

How can I ensure these also get loaded in the latestInspection on the Yard resource?